# React state defind as property deep clone returns 'is undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to write a simple ToDo app.

Clicking on `TodoItem` should remove a item from state but when I do this I'm getting a `TypeError: this.state is undefined`. I don't know what is wrong.

My code looks like this:

#### ---- App.js  ----

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: {
      item1: { text: "Nazwa item1", isDone: false },
      item2: { text: "Nazwa item2", isDone: false },
      item3: { text: "Nazwa item3", isDone: false },
      item4: { text: "Nazwa item4", isDone: false }
    }
  };

  removeItem(key) {
    const items = { ...this.state.items }; // TypeError: this.state is undefined
    console.log(items);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(this.state.items).map(key => (
            <TodoItem
              removeItem={this.removeItem}
              index={key}
              key={key}
              item={this.state.items[key]}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### ---- TodoItem.js  ----

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = props => {
    return (
        <li onClick={() => props.removeItem(props.index)}>
            {props.item.text}
            {props.item.isDone ? "zrobione" : "niezrobione"}
        </li>
    );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `this` is bound to your function and not to the class.

To prevent that you can use an arrow function to keep the binding of `this` to the class, or calling `.bind` method

That should make it work:

```
 removeItem = (key) => {
    const items = { ...this.state.items };
    console.log(items);
  }
```

or that:

```
removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)}
```

Here is a more [in-depth article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Maybe, if they have the right transpiling setup (which they probably do). But a good answer says **what** it changed, and **why**, and **how** it works. (And probably removes the hopefully-now-erroneous comment.) In any case, this is an opt-repeated duplicate well covered by previous answers.

Comment: Changing to arrow function solved a problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am a fool for these points. :(